# Can't rake db:migrate ArgumentError: comparison of Fixnum with String failed

Tags: mysql, rake

This is the oddest error I've ever seen.

I'm trying to deploy rails with a app server and a remote db server.
I can run `rails dbconsole` and login to the the database just fine from the app server.
I can also run `rake db:drop && rake db:create` just fine as well but when I run `rake db:migrate` all hell breaks lose with errors I've never seen before dealing with migrating a db. I bet it's a simple fix that i'm not seeing but please have a look and tell me what I can to fix this. Thank you all who try!

I can run db:migrate on my local machine and it works just fine but when I deploy I get:

```
rake aborted!
ArgumentError: comparison of Fixnum with String failed

ArgumentError: comparison of Fixnum with String failed

ArgumentError: comparison of String with 0 failed

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

So then I run it with trace and it still doesn't give me any want to fix it

```
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
rake aborted!
ArgumentError: comparison of Fixnum with String failed
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/logger.rb:366:in `<'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/logger.rb:366:in `add'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/logger.rb:452:in `error'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:428:in `rescue in log'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:425:in `log'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:286:in `execute'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:220:in `execute'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:300:in `execute_and_free'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:414:in `tables'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:421:in `table_exists?'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/schema_migration.rb:17:in `create_table'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:878:in `initialize'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:764:in `new'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:764:in `up'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:742:in `migrate'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:42:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
ArgumentError: comparison of Fixnum with String failed
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/logger.rb:366:in `<'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/logger.rb:366:in `add'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/logger.rb:452:in `error'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/log_subscriber.rb:85:in `rescue in finish'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/log_subscriber.rb:83:in `finish'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications/fanout.rb:96:in `finish'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications/fanout.rb:40:in `block in finish'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications/fanout.rb:40:in `each'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications/fanout.rb:40:in `finish'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:36:in `finish'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:25:in `instrument'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:420:in `log'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:286:in `execute'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:220:in `execute'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:300:in `execute_and_free'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:414:in `tables'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:421:in `table_exists?'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/schema_migration.rb:17:in `create_table'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:878:in `initialize'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:764:in `new'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:764:in `up'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:742:in `migrate'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:42:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
ArgumentError: comparison of String with 0 failed
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/logger.rb:273:in `<='
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/logger.rb:273:in `debug?'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:37:in `sql'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/subscriber.rb:68:in `finish'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/log_subscriber.rb:83:in `finish'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications/fanout.rb:96:in `finish'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications/fanout.rb:40:in `block in finish'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications/fanout.rb:40:in `each'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications/fanout.rb:40:in `finish'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:36:in `finish'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:25:in `instrument'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:420:in `log'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:286:in `execute'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:220:in `execute'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:300:in `execute_and_free'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:414:in `tables'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:421:in `table_exists?'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/schema_migration.rb:17:in `create_table'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:878:in `initialize'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:764:in `new'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:764:in `up'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:742:in `migrate'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:42:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/home/apps/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

Answer (score 1):

Face Palm.

I had this in my environment file and it was causing the issue:

```
config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
config.logger.level = 'DEBUG'
```

Changed `config.logger.level = 'DEBUG'` to `config.log_level = 'DEBUG'`

All is well now.